# Show that $K_1\cap K_2\cap \dots,K_N$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $K_1,K_2,\dots,K_N$ be compact subsets of the mectric space $(X,d)$.

Show that $K_1\cap K_2\cap \dots,K_N$ is compact.

**My approach:**

I think I should use the definition of compact sets in my textbook:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $K\subseteq X$ is compact if every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $K$.

I can't get further than this. Can you help?

**Update:**
What if it was union instead of intersection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an arbitrary sequence $\{x_n\}\subset K_1\cap K_2\cap...\cap K_N$. This means that the sequence is contained in each $K_i,\,i=1,..,N$. Now for $K_1$ you can find a convergent subsequence (still contained in all $K_i$ and in particular in $K_2$ ) with limit in $K_1$. From it you find a further convergent subsequence in $K_2$ with limit also in $K_2$, and so on. Finally you find a convergent subsequence which has a limit in each $K_i$ as $K_i$ are compact. Also the limit is unique and is contained in each $K_i\Rightarrow$ is contained in the intersection.

If you had to prove that $\cup K_i$ is compact, then again taking an arbitrary sequence $\{x_n\}\subset K_1\cup K_2\cup...\cup K_N$ you want to find a convergent subsequence with limit again in the union. You have that each $x_n$ is contained in at least one $K_i$. Notice that because there are finite number of $K_i$, there must be some index $i_0$ such that $K_{i_0}$ contains infinitly many terms of the seuqence, otherwise if each $K_i$ contains only finitly many terms, the sequence would consist only of finite number of terms. So, in $K_{i_0}$ there is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, call it $\{x_{n_k}\}$, and because $K_{i_0}$ is compact there is a convergent (further) subsequence of it with limit in $K_{i_0}$ and therefore also in the union.

Comment: "Now for $K_1$ you can find a convergent subsequence". How can I do that?

Comment: Because $K_1$ is compact and the definition in your textbook says that you can find a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @macurie see the edit that I made. Now it is more clear.

Comment: Ok, so the argument is that because I can find a convergent subsequence in $K_1$, I can also find one in $K_2$ (and is it the same subsequence)?

Comment: @macurie Denote the convergent subsequence in $K_1$ by $x_{n_k}$. Then $x_{n_k}\to a_1\in K_1$ and also you have $\{x_{n_k}\}\subset K_2\Rightarrow$ you can find a further subsequence $\{x_{n_{k_l}}\}\subset \{x_{n_k}\}\subset \{x_n\}\subset K_1\cap K_2\cap...\cap K_N$ with a limit $a_2\in K_2$, and so on. Finally you see that all $a_1,a_2,...,a_N$ are actually one and the same point, and all are in the intersection.

Comment: What if it was the union ($K_1\cup K_2\cup\dots K_N$) that I need to show is compact instead of the intersection? Could you add this case to your answer?

Comment: @macurie I added this case, too.

Comment: In your argument: *"otherwise if each $K_i$ contains only finitly many terms, the sequence would consist only of finite number of terms."* How do I know that the sequence consists of an infinite number of terms?

Comment: By definition a sequence is an countably infinite set of elements numbered with the naturals numbers.

Comment: Is this also true if the sequence is finite?

Comment: There are no finite sequences, at least in the context here. The definition of compactness requires a sequence that is infinite. Otherwise you can not talk about a limit at all.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that in a metric space compact sets are closed. Intersection of closed sets are closed. And closed subset of a compact set is compact. These three facts imply the conclusion.

These all statements are valid if we consider a Hausdorff topological space, as a generalisation of metric space. So the above claim is true for an Hausdorff space.

Comment: This is true in any Hausdorff space.

Comment: Yes. But OP asked this qes in case of metric space, so I mentioned that.

Comment: Sure, just thought I would add the reference.

Answer (score 2):

A set is compact if every cover has a finite subcover.

So if you take the intersection of non-empty sets, each of which has a finite subcover, does it follow the elements in all of them also has a finite subcover?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, arbitrary intersection (not only finite) of compact subsets is also compact. This is pretty easy to see: in metric spaces, compact subsets are closed, so their intersection is also closed. On the other hand, the closed subset of a compact set is also compact: suppose $K$ is compact and $N \subset K$ is closed. Take any open cover $N \subset \bigcup U_i$ of $N$. As $K - N$ is open, consider open cover $K \subset (K - N) \cup \bigcup U_i$. As $K$ is compact, it has some finite subcover $K \subset V_1 \cup ... \cup V_n$. If $K - N$ is one of the $V_i$, say $V_1$, $V_2 \cup ... \cup V_n$ covers $N$, and is a finite subcover of the original cover $N \subset \bigcup U_i$.

Thus, as closed subset of compact set is compact, and intersection of compact set is a closed subset of any of them, it is compact.

On the other hand, a finite union of compact sets is compact, but infinite one no longer necessarily is!